# Transfer function of a System Diagram

Tags: diagram, linear

I would like to have some help on this system:

[image: System Diagram]

I have to consider that all initial conditions at t = 0 are null. I've tried some things and I have some answers but I don't know if they are true. Could someone shed some light on this?

Here is what I've tried:

[image: calculations]

([Original image showing calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwDgP.jpg))

Is this right? or wrong?

Also, is this system asymptotically stable if and only if a <0 ? Or does B effect on that?

Comment: I can't see anything particularly wrong with it. Did you expect something else or more? Do you perhaps want to add another effort with a different answer and see where it went wrong?

Comment: I just want to know if this equation is the right way of representing this diagram, because I wasn't sure if it was, all I want is the H(s) of the diagram, if it is wrong, another option would be good :D

Comment: I think you're good. The input of the integrator is \$bx(t) - ay(t) \$ so the output is \$y(t) = \int_0^t (bx(\tau) - ay(\tau)) d\tau\$ which is a differential equation you then solve. The only comments I'd have are only minor.

Comment: @SvenB Would you change anything? or Put something else?

Comment: It looks right to me, you can convert it to laplace sooner in the equation to make life easier on you

Comment: The block diagram represents the classical active first-order lowpass.

Comment: added a question to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, personally. The diagram at the bottom has a + on the top left to signify adding bX(s) and a negative at the bottom to signify subtracting KY(s).

This is probably what SeventyMTB had in mind when he said you could save yourself trouble by using the Laplace earlier on.

[image: My approach]

Comment: I see, thanks, but is this system asymptotically stable if and only if a <0 ?

Comment: Yes, for a > 0 (or K in my diagram), you get a pole on the left hand side of the s-plane, which is stable. For a = 0, it is marginally stable (the system will oscillate infinitely to any input), and for a < 0, the system has an unstable pole on the right hand side of the s-plane. I can draw this out if you wish.

Comment: Another fun fact is that b does effect the stability of the system (too large a b will make the system unstable), but this depends partially on the sampling frequency of the control system.

Comment: @Tri "sampling frequency of the control system" This is incorrect, the system is of continuous time. There is no sampling involved here, and the system is stable for any non-infinite \$b\$. You could argue that a discrete version of the system could be unstable, but then a discretization method (zoh, euler, tustin, ...) should be mentioned explicitly, as some will guarantee stability and some won't.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When I said "sampling frequency" I assumed that Matheus would understand that I was talking about what would happen if you implemented this in the real world with a computer, but I also didn't want to go into too much detail unless he asked more of me.